# Equivalent of C++11 unordered_map for an older version of C++

Tags: c++, hashmap, unordered-map

What is the equivalent of C++11 `std::unorderd_map`¹ for an older version of C++²? I've tried `std::tr1::unordered_map`, unfortunately my compiler doesn't support it.

---

¹ I really need the benefit of an `unordered_map`, i.e. *O(1)* time access on average.

² I'm printing `__cplusplus` and it says `1`. I'm not certain which C++ standard the compiler conforms to.

Comment: what is `c++1`?

Comment: There is no such thing as "C++1", no matter what your `__cplusplus` macro expanded to. The better way to get your compiler version is through your compiler's command line option (if any).

Comment: @NickyC can you please answer my questions in my previous comment? Would it make sense to say an older version of (c++, compiler) that doesn't have std::unordered_map?

Comment: I have answered you.

Comment: I'm assuming you're using an old version of GCC - versions of GCC before 4.7 had a bug where the `__cplusplus` macro would have the value 1 instead of something like `199711L`.

Can you not compile your code with a compiler more recent than a at-least-four-years-old GCC?

Comment: @JamesPicone glad to know but no I cannot use the latest compiler. I need to edit the question.

Comment: Whatever you need, if you cant find an acceptably licensed implementation online, roll your own.  I always would prefer to roll my own, but the best business decision is use whats available and acceptably licensed.  I would love to have a proper and good excuse to give my boss to roll my own data structure such as an unordered map.  If you cant roll your own, go to a free lancer and then ask yourself why you can use one, but cant make one.  FWI: Should only take a few days to roll a unordered map and a few more for proper testing.

Comment: @codekaizer and all. I've edited my question. Does it make sense now?

Comment: @EdChum, off-topic hmm. Am just curious if any StackExchange site is suitable for this type of question? Anyways I've edited the question to meet the community standards, _hopefully_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your compiler truly *is* giving you a value of `1` for `__cplusplus` when compiling C++ code, it is non-conforming<sup>(a)</sup>.

In terms of getting an un-ordered map implementation for pre-C++11 compilers, you may want to look into Boost - a large chunk of what comes into standard C++ shows up first there :-) The [un-ordered map](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_36_0/doc/html/boost/unordered_map.html) is available as early as Boost 1.36 in 2008 so should be okay for at least C++03-conforming compilers.

In addition, although *parts* of Boost need building into libraries, un-ordered maps are not one of those parts. As a [header-only feature](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html#header-only-libraries), you need simply include the header file in your code and use it. For example, the following program prints `Hello, world.` with absolutely *no* extra libraries included (I used the *very* basic `g++ -o testprog testprog.cpp` to compile it):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/unordered_map.hpp>
int main() {
    boost::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> x;
    x["hi"] = "Hello";
    x["planet"] = "world";
    std::cout << x["hi"] << ", " << x["planet"] << ".\n";
}
```

---

If, for some reason, Boost *isn't* suitable, the properties for the standard un-ordered map are basically average constant time complexity for everything, so pretty much any half-decent hash-table implementation should be workable as well. But I'd go that route *only* if you can't get the Boost one working - I'd prefer it just based on its known code quality.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Each iteration of the standard (at least from C++98) should have a very specific value set, such as per the C++11 standard:

> The name `__cplusplus` is defined to the value `201103L` when compiling a C++ translation unit.

The values for each iteration should be:

```
pre-C++11  199711L
    C++11  201103L
    C++14  201402L
    C++17  201703L
```

The most *likely* reason it may be non-conforming is that you're using a pre-4.7 variant of `g++` - there was a decade-old bug where it reported the `__cplusplus` version to be `1` rather than the "proper" value.

Comment: @paxdialo Forget the c++1. That's not my original problem. I meant an older version of c++ that doesn't have std::unordered_map. Can you post an answer in that context?

Comment: @MasterJEET, have de-emphasised the `__cplusplus` issue, have a read of the update to see if it's useful.

Comment: @paxdialo very informative. Now I know there isn't any unordered_map equivalent for older `c++`. `boost` is not an option as per my third description.

Comment: @MasterJEET, the majority of Boost is actually header-only stuff, including the un-ordered map. No building or using libraries is required, just include the headers and go. Will clarify.

Comment: @paxiablo  I've taken _subjectivity_ out of the question, as it doesn't suit the community standards, and posting it here so that no one why wonders why you bothered to describe so much. 
---
**If there's no such thing, then is there any preferred _open source impementation_ of the same that I can use? When I say _open source implementaion_, I don't mean any third party library that I can just add to my project; rather complete source code that I can put in my code. Probably this is why I can't use `boost`.**

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using an old/odd/nonconforming compiler and/or standard library. The `__cplusplus` macro should be defined to an integer representing a `YYYYMM` date that indicates the supported C++ standard.

Apart from using a modern compiler and standard lib you have some alternatives for a C++11 `std::unordered_map` like hash map implementation:

- `std::tr1::unordered_map`: The predecessor of the C++11 version, if your std lib supports it.
- [Boost.Unordered](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/unordered/) provides `boost::unordered_map` that only requires a C++98 compiler and mimics the interface of the modern `std::unordered_map` as closely as possible.

Comment: `std::tr1::unordered_map` that I've tried, a minimal google search will return links that ask you to try that. I'm here only after that. Still good that you mentioned, can be useful for others. And for the `boost`, don't I need the precompiled library for that? Hence doesn't fulfill my third description point. And in fact, I included my third description keeping in mind that people will suggest `boost`.

Comment: Well, if you wanted to exclude Boost explictly, why didn’t you say so in your question? And no, compilation wouldn’t have been necessary. Boost.Unordered is header only.

Comment: Well when I last commented, I wasn't aware of _header-only library_ concept. paxdiablo's answer clarified things for me.